# Why does my fruit respawn outside of the boundaries in snake game?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a snake game in which if the snake eats the first fruit and in 2 seconds eats the second fruit then it's score multiplied by 2. If the snake eats the second fruit in 1 second then the score is multiplied by 3. If the snake eats the second fruit in 3 seconds then the score is increased just by 1 and so on ... But after the snake eats about 5-6 fruits the 7th fruit respawns outside of the boundaries. This the "drawing" function

```
void make_stage() {
score = 0;
int x = 9, y = 9;
int x1 = 8, y1 = 9;
int x2 = 7, y2 = 9;
int x3 = 6, y3 = 9;
int x4 = 5, y4 = 9;
char dir = 'd';
char input = 'e';
gotoxy(x, y);
printf("a");
gotoxy(x1, y1);
printf("*");
gotoxy(x2, y2);
printf("*");
gotoxy(x3, y3);
printf("*");
gotoxy(x4, y4);
printf("*");
for (int i = 1; i <= 17; i++) {
    gotoxy(i, 1);
    printf("#");
    gotoxy(1, i);
    printf("#");
    gotoxy(17, i);
    printf("#");
    gotoxy(i, 17);
    printf("#");
}
srand(time(NULL));
fruitx = rand() % 17;
fruity = rand() % 17;
gotoxy(fruitx, fruity);
printf("@");
}
```

And this is the logic function:

```
void snake_move() {
int x = 9, y = 9;
int x1 = 8, y1 = 9;
int x2 = 7, y2 = 9;
int x3 = 6, y3 = 9;
int x4 = 5, y4 = 9;
char dir = 'd';
char input = 'e';
while (1) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    if (x == fruitx && y == fruity) {
        fruitx = rand() % 17;
        fruity = rand() % 17;
        score += 1;
        gotoxy(fruitx, fruity);
        printf("@");
    }
    input = _getch();
    if ((dir == 'w' && input != 's') || (dir == 'a' && input != 'd') || (dir == 's' && input != 'w') || (dir == 'd' && input != 'a')) {
        if (input == 'w') {
            gotoxy(x4, y4);
            printf(" ");
            x4 = x3; x3 = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = x;
            y4 = y3; y3 = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = y;
            y = y - 1;
            if (y == 1) {
                gameover();
                break;
            }
            if (x == x4 && y == y4) {
                gameover();
                break;
            }
            gotoxy(x, y);
            printf("a");
            gotoxy(x1, y1);
            printf("*");
            gotoxy(x2, y2);
            printf("*");
            gotoxy(x3, y3);
            printf("*");
            gotoxy(x4, y4);
            printf("*");
            dir = 'w';
        }
        if (input == 'a') {
            gotoxy(x4, y4);
            printf(" ");
            x4 = x3; x3 = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = x;
            y4 = y3; y3 = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = y;
            x = x - 1;
            if (x == 1) {
                gameover();
                break;
            }
            if (x == x4 && y == y4) {
                gameover();
                break;
            }
            gotoxy(x, y);
            printf("a");
            gotoxy(x1, y1);
            printf("*");
            gotoxy(x2, y2);
            printf("*");
            gotoxy(x3, y3);
            printf("*");
            gotoxy(x4, y4);
            printf("*");
            dir = 'a';
        }
        if (input == 's') {
            gotoxy(x4, y4);
            printf(" ");
            x4 = x3; x3 = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = x;
            y4 = y3; y3 = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = y;
            y = y + 1;
            if (y == 17) {
                gameover();
                break;
            }
            if (x == x4 && y == y4) {
                gameover();
                break;
            }
            gotoxy(x, y);
            printf("a");
            gotoxy(x1, y1);
            printf("*");
            gotoxy(x2, y2);
            printf("*");
            gotoxy(x3, y3);
            printf("*");
            gotoxy(x4, y4);
            printf("*");
            dir = 's';
        }
        if (input == 'd') {
            gotoxy(x4, y4);
            printf(" ");
            x4 = x3; x3 = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = x;
            y4 = y3; y3 = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = y;
            x = x + 1;
            if (x == 17) {
                gameover();
                break;
            }
            if (x == x4 && y == y4) {
                gameover();
                break;
            }
            gotoxy(x, y);
            printf("a");
            gotoxy(x1, y1);
            printf("*");
            gotoxy(x2, y2);
            printf("*");
            gotoxy(x3, y3);
            printf("*");
            gotoxy(x4, y4);
            printf("*");
            dir = 'd';
        }
    }
    if (input == 'p') {
        gameover();
        break;
    }
}
}
```

and this is the entire source code just in case!

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<windows.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<time.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<process.h>
    int height = 17, width = 17;
    typedef struct RECORD {
        char name[100];
        int score;
        int minute;
        int sec;
    }record; //이름, 점수, 시간을 저장할 구조체
    int score;
    int fruitx, fruity;
    record nowrec;
    
    int over = 0;
    
void gotoxy(int x, int y);          //Input location
void make_stage();                  //stage
int getCommand();                   // Keyboard input
void gameover();                    //Gameover screen
void startscr();                    //Start screen
void snake_move();                  //Snake movements
void rank_call();                   //Displaying rank
void rankrecord();                  //personal records
    void cursor(int i);             //
    void stopwatch();               //stop watch 
    
    int main(void) {
        startscr();
        return 0;
    }
    
    void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
        COORD pos = { 30 + x * 2, 10 + y };
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), pos);
    }
    
    void make_stage() {
        score = 0;
        int x = 9, y = 9;
        int x1 = 8, y1 = 9;
        int x2 = 7, y2 = 9;
        int x3 = 6, y3 = 9;
        int x4 = 5, y4 = 9;
        char dir = 'd';
        char input = 'e';
        gotoxy(x, y);
        printf("a");
        gotoxy(x1, y1);
        printf("*");
        gotoxy(x2, y2);
        printf("*");
        gotoxy(x3, y3);
        printf("*");
        gotoxy(x4, y4);
        printf("*");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 17; i++) {
            gotoxy(i, 1);
            printf("#");
            gotoxy(1, i);
            printf("#");
            gotoxy(17, i);
            printf("#");
            gotoxy(i, 17);
            printf("#");
        }
        srand(time(NULL));
        fruitx = rand() % 17;
        fruity = rand() % 17;
        gotoxy(fruitx, fruity);
        printf("@");
    }
    
    int getCommand() {
        if (_kbhit()) {
            return _getch();
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    void cursor(int i) {
        CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cursorInfo = { 0, };
        cursorInfo.dwSize = 1;
        cursorInfo.bVisible = i;
        SetConsoleCursorInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &cursorInfo);
    }
    
    void rank_call() {
        FILE* rank;
        char reading[100];
        if (fopen_s(&rank, "rank.txt", "r") != 0) printf("no record\n");
        else {
            printf("\n");
            while ((fgets(reading, 100, rank) != NULL)) printf("%s", reading);
            fclose(rank);
            printf("\n");
        }
    
    }
    
    void rankrecord() {
        printf("\npress enter to proceed...\n");
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        printf("\n\n\n\n\n\npress r to record your ranking...\n");
        char input = _getch();
        if (input == 'r') {
            FILE* rank;
            fopen_s(&rank, "rank.txt", "a");
        rerun:
            printf("enter your name: ");
            gets_s(nowrec.name, sizeof(nowrec.name));
            if (strlen(nowrec.name) < 3) {
                printf("name must be at least 3 words...\n\n");
                goto rerun;
            }
            while (1) {
                printf("your name is %s.\nyour score is %d.\nyour clear time is %d : %d.\n\n", nowrec.name, nowrec.score, nowrec.minute, nowrec.sec);
                printf("if your name is incorrect, press n to correct\nif not, press y to continue...\n\n");
                input = _getch();
                if (input == 'n') goto rerun;
                else if (input == 'y') break;
                else printf("wrong input\n\n");
            }
            fprintf(rank, "%s %d %d : %d\n", nowrec.name, nowrec.score, nowrec.minute, nowrec.sec);
            fclose(rank);
            printf("saved!\n");
        }
    }
    
    void startscr()
    {
    
        system("mode con cols=100 lines=40");
    start:
    
        system("cls");
        printf("   ******   **    *       *      *    *  ******           ******      *        **    **    ******   \n");
        printf("   *        * *   *      * *     *   *   *                *          * *      *  *  *  *   *        \n");
        printf("   ******   *  *  *     *****    ****    ******           *  ***    *****     *  *  *  *   ******   \n");
        printf("        *   *   * *    *     *   *   *   *                *    *   *     *   *    **    *  *        \n");
        printf("   ******   *    **   *       *  *    *  ******           ******  *       *  *    **    *  ******   \n");
        printf("\npress s to start game\n");
        printf("press r to see ranking\n");
        printf("press x to exit\n:");
        char input = _getch();
        if (input == 's') {
            system("cls");
            cursor(0);
            make_stage();
            HANDLE thread1 = _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, (_beginthreadex_proc_type)stopwatch, NULL, 0, NULL);
            Sleep(1);
            HANDLE thread2 = _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, (_beginthreadex_proc_type)snake_move, NULL, 0, NULL);
            WaitForSingleObject(thread2, INFINITE);
    
        }
        else if (input == 'r') {
            rank_call();
            printf("press enter to continue...");
            while (getchar() != '\n');
            goto start;
        }
        else if (input == 'x') exit(0);
        else {
            printf("wrong input\n");
            printf("press enter to continue...");
            while (getchar() != '\n');
            goto start;
        }
    }
    
    void gameover() {
        over = 1;
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        printf("        ******      *        **    **    ******            ****   *       *  ******   *****         \n");
        printf("        *          * *      *  *  *  *   *                *    *   *     *   *        *    *        \n");
        printf("        *  ***    *****     *  *  *  *   ******           *    *    *   *    ******   *****         \n");
        printf("        *    *   *     *   *    **    *  *                *    *     * *     *        *    *        \n");
        printf("        ******  *       *  *    **    *  ******            ****       *      ******   *     *      \n");
        cursor(1);
        rankrecord();
        printf("press any key to back to title...");
        _getch();
        startscr();
    }
    
    void snake_move() {
        int x = 9, y = 9;
        int x1 = 8, y1 = 9;
        int x2 = 7, y2 = 9;
        int x3 = 6, y3 = 9;
        int x4 = 5, y4 = 9;
        char dir = 'd';
        char input = 'e';
        while (1) {
            srand(time(NULL));
            if (x == fruitx && y == fruity) {
                fruitx = rand() % 17;
                fruity = rand() % 17;
                score += 1;
                gotoxy(fruitx, fruity);
                printf("@");
            }
            input = _getch();
            if ((dir == 'w' && input != 's') || (dir == 'a' && input != 'd') || (dir == 's' && input != 'w') || (dir == 'd' && input != 'a')) {
                if (input == 'w') {
                    gotoxy(x4, y4);
                    printf(" ");
                    x4 = x3; x3 = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = x;
                    y4 = y3; y3 = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = y;
                    y = y - 1;
                    if (y == 1) {
                        gameover();
                        break;
                    }
                    if (x == x4 && y == y4) {
                        gameover();
                        break;
                    }
                    gotoxy(x, y);
                    printf("a");
                    gotoxy(x1, y1);
                    printf("*");
                    gotoxy(x2, y2);
                    printf("*");
                    gotoxy(x3, y3);
                    printf("*");
                    gotoxy(x4, y4);
                    printf("*");
                    dir = 'w';
                }
                if (input == 'a') {
                    gotoxy(x4, y4);
                    printf(" ");
                    x4 = x3; x3 = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = x;
                    y4 = y3; y3 = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = y;
                    x = x - 1;
                    if (x == 1) {
                        gameover();
                        break;
                    }
                    if (x == x4 && y == y4) {
                        gameover();
                        break;
                    }
                    gotoxy(x, y);
                    printf("a");
                    gotoxy(x1, y1);
                    printf("*");
                    gotoxy(x2, y2);
                    printf("*");
                    gotoxy(x3, y3);
                    printf("*");
                    gotoxy(x4, y4);
                    printf("*");
                    dir = 'a';
                }
                if (input == 's') {
                    gotoxy(x4, y4);
                    printf(" ");
                    x4 = x3; x3 = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = x;
                    y4 = y3; y3 = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = y;
                    y = y + 1;
                    if (y == 17) {
                        gameover();
                        break;
                    }
                    if (x == x4 && y == y4) {
                        gameover();
                        break;
                    }
                    gotoxy(x, y);
                    printf("a");
                    gotoxy(x1, y1);
                    printf("*");
                    gotoxy(x2, y2);
                    printf("*");
                    gotoxy(x3, y3);
                    printf("*");
                    gotoxy(x4, y4);
                    printf("*");
                    dir = 's';
                }
                if (input == 'd') {
                    gotoxy(x4, y4);
                    printf(" ");
                    x4 = x3; x3 = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = x;
                    y4 = y3; y3 = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = y;
                    x = x + 1;
                    if (x == 17) {
                        gameover();
                        break;
                    }
                    if (x == x4 && y == y4) {
                        gameover();
                        break;
                    }
                    gotoxy(x, y);
                    printf("a");
                    gotoxy(x1, y1);
                    printf("*");
                    gotoxy(x2, y2);
                    printf("*");
                    gotoxy(x3, y3);
                    printf("*");
                    gotoxy(x4, y4);
                    printf("*");
                    dir = 'd';
                }
            }
            if (input == 'p') {
                gameover();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    void stopwatch() {
        clock_t s, n;
        s = clock();
        while (1) {
            n = clock();
            cursor(0);
            gotoxy(14, 0);
            printf(" %d : %d", ((n - s) / 1000) / 60, ((n - s) / 1000) % 60);
            if (over == 1) {
                break;
            }
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        gotoxy(14, 0);
        printf(" ****  ");
        nowrec.minute = ((n - s) / 1000) / 60;
        nowrec.sec = ((n - s) / 1000) % 60;
        return;
    }
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of your field supposed to be?

Comment: height = 17 and width = 17.

Comment: Where are you declaring ```score```, ```fruitx```, and ```fruity```? Without the entire source code, it's going to be difficult to solve the problem.

Comment: I added the entire source code now. They are global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that

```c
rand() % x
```

will give you values in the range **[0, x-1]**.

With this in mind, let's look at

```c
fruitx = rand() % 17;
fruity = rand() % 17;
gotoxy(fruitx, fruity);
printf("@");
```

When you feed `rand() % 17` into `gotoxy()` like this, you can expect that `goto(0, 0)` is possible.

I modified the above code to look like this

```c
fruitx = rand() % 17;
fruity = rand() % 17;
gotoxy(0, 0);
printf("@");
```

to see what would happen, and the fruit turned up **outside the field** in the top left.

```c
void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
    COORD pos = { 30 + x * 2, 10 + y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), pos);
}
```

The problem is that your definition of `gotoxy()` is such that feeding it `(0, 0)` as coordinates puts the cursor outside the boundary to begin with. Furthermore, passing `(1, 1)` puts it in the corner, making it apart of the wall, which is also illegal I'm guessing.

To fix this, you either need to adjust your mathematics in `gotoxy()` or make a new function that transforms your field coordinates into global coordinates. This way, `(0, 0)` would correspond to the actual upper left (just inside the boundary) and so on.

The easiest fix is just to modify it like so

```c
    fruitx = 2 + rand() % 15;
    fruity = 2 + rand() % 15;
    gotoxy(fruitx, fruity);
    printf("@");
```

**This should happen everywhere you're spawning fruit.**